# Repeat values every 5th space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values

- 1231 (in A1)
- 1232 (in A2)
- 2423 (in A3)
- 2132 (in A4)

However, for reporting purposes, I want to show them in every 5th cell. Example

- 1231 (in A1)
- 1232 (in A6)
- 2423 (in A11)
- 2132 (in A16)

And in between spaces as blank. Any help on doing this with formulas is appreciated. I just can't find a way using search as I don't know what to search.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure? I mean the first two will be FOUR rows apart, while all others will be FIVE rows apart...

Comment: I meant 5 rows apart. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are in column A.

The formula will need to be in a different column. Let's use column B (but you can use whatever you like).

In cell B1 enter this formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),5)-1,"",INDEX(A:A,ROW()/5+1))
```

Copy downwards as far as needed.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!